# Building List (ForEach) with custom data models which inherited from same protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

basically I'm building an app with SwitUI and I have 4 data models which are inherited from same protocol:

```
protocol Item: Codable
{

}


// Intializing Identity Data type which supports:
struct IdentityItem: Item, Identifiable {
    var kind: String = "IdentityItem"
    var id: String
    let name: String
    let middleName: String
    let lastName: String
    let gender: String
    let birthDate: Date
    let nationalID: String
}

// Intializing Note Data type which supports:
struct NoteItem: Item, Identifiable {
    var kind: String = "NoteItem"
    var id: String
    let title: String
    let date: Date
    let textBlob: String
}

// Intializing Credit Card Data type which supports:
struct CreditCardItem: Item, Identifiable {
    var kind: String = "CreditCardItem"
    var id: String
    let title: String
    let bankName: String
    let cardNumber: String
    let cardHolderName: String
    let expirationDate: Date
    let cardPin: Int
    let cardCvv: Int
}

// Intializing Login Credentials Data type which supports:
struct LoginItem: Item, Identifiable {
    var kind: String = "LoginItem"
    var id: String
    let title: String
    let username: String
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let website: String
}
```

Let's say that I have 3 various items in an array like this:

```
@State var itemArray: [Item]() = [creditItem1,noteItem2,loginItem3]
```

While creating a list of these items, I cannot access the properties of each item for creating custom views with various arguments.

How can I build a List with custom views from the parameters of each itemArray object?

While doing  `ForEach(itemArray, id: \.self){ item in }` for id argument just `.self` appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare common properties in protocol, like below

```
protocol Item: Codable
{
    var id: String { get set }   // << here !!
    var kind: String { get set } // << here !!
}


// Intializing Identity Data type which supports:
struct IdentityItem: Item, Identifiable {
    var kind: String = "IdentityItem"
    var id: String
    // .. other code here
...
```

Comment: I tried the same way but it keeps giving "Protocol 'Item' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" error for all cases.

Comment: @NicatMuzaffarli, updated. tested with `var itemArray: [Item] = [creditItem1,noteItem2,loginItem3]`

Comment: Right now I'm getting an error(Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred) while retrieving data and passing it to itemArray from controller class.

Comment: you can check project files from here: https://github.com/Glockx/Passlock